# Forward variable in route

Tags: symfony4

I'm trying to forward a variable for a route in the twig template. But my method doesn't work.

The user can create a projet there is multiple personnages and the route for the personnage is `admin/projet/{idProjet}/personnages/{idPersonnage}` So when i'm in the personnage show I need to recup the `idProjet`

I tried to pass in the render but not work too

My Projet Controller

```
 /**
 * @Route("admin/projet/{id}", name="projet_show", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function show(Projet $projet, Request $request): Response
{
    $chapitres = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Chapitre::class)
        ->findByProjet($projet->getId());

    $personnages = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository(Personnages::class)
        ->findByProjet($projet->getId());

    $idProjet = $projet->getId();

    return $this->render('projet/show.html.twig', [
        'projet' => $projet,
        'idProjet' => $idProjet,
        'chapitres' => $chapitres,
        'personnages' => $personnages
    ]);
}
```

Projet show in twig

```
{% for personnage in personnages %}
<div class="list-group">
<a href="{{ path('personnages_show', {'idPersonnage': 
personnage.id}, 
{ 'idProjet': idProjet}) }}" class="list-group-item list-group- 
item-action">
{% if personnage.role == 'Héros' %}
<i class="fas fa-chess-queen"></i> {{ personnage.firstName }} {{ 
personnage.lastName }}
{% elseif personnage.role == 'Secondaire'%}
<i class="fas fa-chess-knight"></i> 
{{ personnage.firstName }} {{ personnage.lastName }}
{% else %}
```

Error message :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template (Some mandatory parameters are missing (`idProjet`) to generate a URL for route `personnages_show`.).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameters for [`path`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#path) are not formatted properly.

```
href="{{ path('personnages_show', {'idPersonnage': personnage.id, 'idProjet': idProjet}) }}"
```

By using extra brackets the `idProject` was being passed as the `absolute` option.

Comment: Ooooh yeeaah it work really thanks, I don't saw it :p